# int to float with bitwise operators in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a function to convert int to float with bit operators. I don't understand why my code doesn't work for all inputs. For example, it works for 2,19,43 and so on, but it outputs -nan for 7,6,13,58 and so on. Can someone please explain me why is this happening? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union{
    int x;
    float fx;
}df;
int find_e(int x,int i){
    if(x&1<<i) return i;
    if(x==0) return -127;
    return find_e(x,--i);
}
float int_to_float(int x){
    df ime;
    ime.x=0;
    int sign = 0;
    if(x<0){x=-x;sign = 1<<31; }
    int position = find_e(x,31);
    int e = position + 127;
    int m = (x&(~(~0<<position)))<<(32-position);
    ime.x |= sign;
    ime.x |= e<<23;
    ime.x |= m>>9;
    return ime.fx;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%f\n", int_to_float(x));
    return 0;
}
```

I use gcc compiler.

Comment: You've crossed the maximum value allowed for int as per C standard. Your compiler is depicting problem with that... Please add the name of compiler too in the question tags.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've got to ask: why??

Comment: Note: Likely fails with `INT_MIN`.  Also does not round correctly for large `int`.  Good enough though as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the type of "m", `int` is signed, and a right shift will sign extend.

```
ime.x |= m>>9;
```

Change all variables that cannot be negative to `unsigned` instead of `int`.

I've fixed it and made some minor changes: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/609c8b2e8a47de4b)